# How to retrieve last 90 days friday dates?

Tags: java, date

I want to display all week ending dates for the last 90 days  in drop down list. How to retrieve the last 90 days friday dates?

Comment: required output in c#/SQL/Jquery?

Comment: and what you have tried ??

Comment: read this (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you an idea (since you tagged JAVA) , in JAVA this can be accomplished using Date API's. For testing i was just checking for 5 weeks  , you could go all the way to 90 weeks. Please note that this provides an idea , can it be optimized , possibly yes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
        DayOfWeek dotw = localDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
        String dayOfTheWeek = dotw.name();

        for (int daysOfTheWeek = 1; daysOfTheWeek < 7; daysOfTheWeek++) {
            if (dayOfTheWeek.equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.name())) {
                break;
            } else {
                localDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().minusDays(daysOfTheWeek);
                dotw = localDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
                dayOfTheWeek = dotw.name();
            }
        }
        ArrayList<LocalDate> localDates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();

        for (int weekCount = 0; weekCount < 5; weekCount++) {
            localDates.add(localDateTime.minusWeeks(weekCount).toLocalDate());
        }
        System.out.println(localDates);

    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you could improve your code in several ways: No need for LocalDateTime (a LocalDate is enough); use the temporal adjusters (for example: previousOrSame to get the previous FRIDAY without having to loop). See for example: http://ideone.com/MRWBxj

Comment: Thanks @assylias , learnt a thing or 2 with that snippet. Thanks agin